Is it realistic for everyone to pursue enlightenment?
In Buddhism, everyone should pursue the path of enlightenment.
In Buddhism, anyone can attain enlightenment.
In Theravada Buddhism, the best way to do so is to become a monk.
In Theravada Buddhism, monks can't prepare food for themselves.
Then how can everyone pursure enlightenment?
One partial answer is that in Buddhism, since pursuing the path of enlightenment would lead one to be better off than otherwise, such as being reborn in one of the levels of the God realm which is higher/better, then dieing in the pursuit of such wouldn't matter. In Buddhism, perhaps it may even be said it doesn't matter if an entire species dies in the pursuit of enlightenment. Propogation of the species in physical form wouldn't matter, if they are all pursuing nirvana.

Buddhist enlightenment has many different paths and at least twelve different stages to pass through as explicated in Mahayana's Shurangama sutra: Fundamental enlightenment is profound indeed... Thus there are totals of twelve single and grouped levels. At last they reach Wonderful Enlightenment and accomplish the Unsurpassed Way...

"The largest room in the world is the room for improvement." Either you're improving yourself, or you are getting worse, because, entropy.

You are asking the wrong audience, so you are getting a lot of answers which fly in different directions.
The place to ask is a Theravada monk, or an experienced layperson.
In general, the (level of) practice one takes on is self-imposed. One doesn't practice Buddhism because they should in the abstract, but because they are convinced they should.
So wondering about abstract hypotheticals such as "what if everyone wanted to leave the lay life" is beyond the scope of useful musings for a Buddhist.
The Buddha started the sāsana for this world, not a hypothetical one.

In case it helps your journey of discovery, I believe you're implicitly invoking the categorical imperative to the admonition that one should become a monk to achieve enlightenment. Most of the answers are either not seeing it in that light, or are rejecting the categorical imperative as a guiding principle - it's far from universally accepted. (BTW, I too was hoping for a more nuanced analysis of the interplay of the philosophical principles, rather than "dirt farmers gonna dirt farm".)

This is a historically contingent question in Buddhism, but it's being laid out here as an abstract, generic philosophical question.
Initially, the tenets of Buddhism were taught only to renunciants. (source) The Buddha of the Pali Canon did not try to convince householders to leave their homes. There are two main reasons for this. First, many householders were illiterate and could not be expected to devote much time to understanding doctrine when they had other jobs to do. Second, Buddhism was envisioned as a way for householders to benefit as well as renunciants; the former by accumulating merit so that they might become enlightened in a future lifetime, and the latter by forming a new kind of community devoted to the correct teachings. It was not expected that there would be a constant stream of new Buddhas anyway.
Centuries later, as many householders became more educated in Buddhist teachings, the concept of a bodhisattva emerged. Initially, in the Ugraparipṛcchā Sūtra, a bodhisattva was a semi-renunciant, who continued his day job with some awareness of enlightenment, but expected only to support the community, not to become a Buddha. Later (to simplify centuries of complex debate), a bodhisattva became a fully enlightened person who voluntarily accepted rebirth in order to continue to enlighten others, which provided a new promise of salvation directly to householders. Now there were multiple ways to achieve freedom from rebirth, which lessened the burden on monks to educate everyone. This is the Buddhism which was common through much of East Asian history, and hence the question of whether everyone ought to be pursuing enlightenment was irrelevant to most East Asian Buddhists including Dōgen.
Much, much later, following the arrival of Protestant Christian ideas in China and Japan, there came the idea that Buddhist meditation could be practiced without taking vows. This is Shunryu Suzuki's Zen Buddhism which is being quoted by one of the other answers.

Correction: The book that @causative referred to (Zen Mind, Beginner's Mind) is not by Daisetsu T. Suzuki -- the early propagator of Zen in the AngloSaxon world -- but by Shunryu Suzuki.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunryū_Suzuki). (I gave my copy of this book to some young Mormon missionaries who in vain tried to convert me ...)

Thank you, corrected!

Buddhism is for those whose eyes have little dust. That is those who are blind cannot see; those who have clear vision need no help to see. But there is a wide intermediate region — can see a bit; need help to see more clearly.
Where are you?
You need to understand that the two statements:

Realistic for everyone
Realistic for me

... are are not merely different in number: if there are 100 or 8 billion 'me-s' and we quantify over the whole set we get 'everyone'.
Rather they are as different as the endless seconds of time from the Big Bang are to now, the vast space of earth, solar system, galaxy is to here.
The Here and Now is where you find yourself, not Buddhism.
And what do you find?
The starting question for any newcomer to a religious/spiritual system has to be

Do I need this?
From there...
What do I need?
From there...
Can you help me to clarify (remove the little dust) what I need?

But if the basic starting point — I am suffering; and I need help — is something you don't relate to at all, then the question is moot — for you!
Enlightenment is secondary; your own recognition of dukha is primary.
Christians call it conviction of sin — it needs to be your clarity on sin, dukha etc. Not some Bible thumping salesman's!! Or whatever is the Buddhism equivalent.

The irony that "constructive selfish" is the only way to help others. Because, there are no 'others'.

Isn't this just simple logic?

In Buddhism, everyone should pursue the path of enlightenment.

Let's treat that as a given - with the understanding that not everyone is a Buddhist.  According to Buddhism, this should mean that even non-Buddhists should pursue the path of enlightenment.

In Buddhism, anyone can attain enlightenment.

That follows from my previous point.

In Theravada Buddhism, the best way to do so is to become a monk.

The best way to do something is not necessarily the only way... and Theravada Buddhism is only a subset of all Buddhism, which is itself only a subset of all beliefs.

In Theravada Buddhism, monks can't prepare food for themselves.

I expect that they can, just that they should not, and for the most part, do not.

Then how can everyone pursure enlightenment?

Because for all the Theravada Buddhists who are monks and do not prepare their own food, there are others who may be Theravada Buddhists but are not monks, who may be other Buddhists, or who may be Non-Buddhists who would be willing to feed the Theravada Buddhist monks while pursuing enlightenment for themselves in their own, less-than-best way.
I see no paradox.

What I know of Buddhism is mostly from Shunryu Suzuki's "Zen Mind, Beginner's Mind." So I can't say whether this applies to Theravada Buddhism. (Although, Suzuki claims that Zen Buddhism is just Buddhism and there aren't different kinds of Buddhism.)
Suzuki has this to say about your question:

To have some deep feeling about Buddhism is not the point; we just do what we should do, like eating supper and going to bed.


Zen is not some kind of excitement, but concentration on our usual daily routine ... Zen is not something to get excited about. Some people start to practice Zen just out of curiosity, and they only make themselves busier. If your practice makes you worse, it is ridiculous. I think that if you try to do zazen once a week, that will make you busy enough. Do not be too interested in Zen. When young people get excited about Zen, they often give up schooling and go to some mountain or forest in order to sit. That kind of interest is not true interest.

He also says that it is not possible to make rapid progress anyway even if you get over-excited about Zen and give up schooling. But just if you do years of regular practice, even just once a week, you will notice a difference in your state of mind.
My favorite quote from Suzuki also applies to your question:

If you are trying to attain enlightenment, you are creating and being driven by karma, and you are wasting your time on your black cushion.

The problem with trying to attain enlightenment is that you have become attached to the concept of attaining something. Being attached to enlightenment is just as harmful to your state of mind (according to Suzuki) as being attached to material things. Instead when you start zazen there is already enlightenment, and you should not try to get something other than what is already there.

Anyway, that is just Suzuki's perspective. I'm not a Buddhist and there are things he says that I don't agree with. I'd say the practice of zazen can help your mind become more peaceful and focused, and it's true that having "gaining ideas" (such as desiring enlightenment) while you are practicing zazen spoils this effect of peacefulness. But I don't think just having a peaceful and focused Zen mind is the meaning of life.
I'd say it's difficult to reconcile Zen with caring for people. (And, if everyone ran away to be a monk leaving no one to grow food, this would certainly cause harm to people.) If you want other people to be happy and healthy, isn't that a gaining idea? If you care, you are attached. But Suzuki's idea is to help people because it's "doing what you should do," without being attached to them, and being neither being upset if harm comes to them nor gratified if they prosper. You just take what comes imperturbably.
Suzuki says in Buddhism we just "do what we should do." But to me, the dilemma is - what is the reason to do "what we should do," if we are not attached to any outcome and are, in effect, indifferent? I don't think he would use this word, "indifferent," but it's difficult for me to see how the state of mind of zazen is not indifferent.

Indifferent, yet still responsive. Doing the right thing in any situation should not be emotional.

I don't think you've thought this argument through, because it is a bit odd.  I mean, I can make a parallel argument like so:

Everyone is capable of being educated, and education is a positive
good.
Higher levels of education leads to lower birthrates (that's an
established fact).
If everyone were perfectly educated, the birthrate would be zero.
If the birthrate is zero, humanity will end.
Therefore we shouldn't educate people for fear of wiping out humanity.

But the nature of humanity is that there are always new people entering the world who need to learn. And the same new people need to learn wisdom, so there's no fear that we will all become monastics at once.

The world is a giant Pyramid Scheme, ha ha :-);

Haha touche! I was thinking of a similar argument: The pinnacle of higher education is a nobel prize. One in a million phds get a nobel. So forget about higher studies. Now one can for various reasons put aside higher studies. But not with this reasoning !


Enlightenment is a big word.
Every Buddhist follower agrees that the
historical Buddha was enlightened (more precisely: Buddha = the
Awakened). But it is not so clear what his insight actually was. We
have to reconstruct it from his first teachings.
The historical Buddha announces to
have discovered the way to end human suffering. The essence of his
doctrine has been formulated as the “Four Noble Truths”. No. 4 is
the “Noble Eightfold Path”, a training program to improve one’s
character.

Nobody knows whether the eightfold path ends actually ends
transmigration by reaching the state of nirvāṇa. Because nobody
verified that the doctrine of transmigration is correct.
Nevertheless it seems a good idea – even from the viewpoint of a
secular wordview:  To reflect, what some practice along the
eightfold path could mean in one’s personal situation.
How to
change the big word “enlightenment” into the small coins of daily life.



With respect, I don't agree with saying that only the Buddha did or could attain enlightenment. It's like saying only one person ever got a PhD. Christianity makes this crucial mistake. Jesus said that others would reach his state and people conveniently ignore that. Why pursue the unattainable? Every single breath that you do better than the last breath is absolutely as valuable as enlightenment. Anything less than that statement is self-contradictory.

@ScottRowe I'm not sure where you see Jo saying Only Buddha.... But yes it's true many many people lay all the troubles of the world at (a dualistic misrepresentation of) Jesus Christ. And then continue with doing exactly what they accuse him of doing

@Rushi yes, perhaps I misread... Not enlightened yet, I guess :-)

@ScottRowe Just to confirm: I do not say that only the Buddha did or could attain enlightenment.

Why is it realistic for everyone to pursue enlightenment?
When I first saw the question, before reading the full text, I thought that the question would concern Immanuel Kant’s 1784 essay on enlightenment. From the essay:

Enlightenment is man's release from his self-incurred immaturity.
Immaturity is man's inability to make use of his understanding without
direction from another.

After I read the question’s text, I was still hoping that some unity could be found between the thinking of an Eighteenth Century Prussian philosopher and modern Buddhism. I was hoping that the two would see enlightenment as the same in some important way.
But it was not to be. I see no overlap between the two notions of enlightenment.
So, here is my answer: if everyone chose the best way to enlightenment and so became a monk, and if monks cannot prepare their own food, then everyone would soon starve. If harvesting fresh fruit directly from the trees is not "preparation," then the population would fall until the bounty of the trees was enough to support the remaining population.
That is what I can offer. If I have completely missed the point of your question, then I also offer my apologies.

I don't see any conflict between Kant's statement and what I understand of Buddhism?

@Scott Rowe. Not conflict, exactly. Just no overlap.

Perhaps. You don't see overcoming immaturity to become self-directed as being the same as overcoming ignorance to become self-aware? To me they're just different phrases for the same thing. Do you agree with the hyperbolic saying, "Everything that rises must converge"? Weird, but I feel it makes sense.

@ScottRowe Yes I too was struck by how widely this answer misses the point. Can think of few classic enlightenment european philosophers more Indian than Kant. Yes Schopenhauer wore his love for Buddhism and Upanishads on his sleeves. But ultimately he too was too overwhelmed by the Buddhist insight that suffering founds the world. Whereas Kant's noumena-phenomena are isomorphic to Vedantic Brahman-maya with precise exactitude
